# Dynamic Structure in C++

Tags: c++

```
struct testing
{
    char lastname[20];        
};

testing *pt = new testing;            
pt->lastname = "McLove";
```

and I got

> 56 C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Untitled2.cpp incompatible types in
>   assignment of 'const char[7]' to 'char[20]'

Why ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char *` for text handling.  The assignment operator for `char *` *does not copy the contents* of the array or string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because compile time arrays are constant. In your struct `testing`, you have an array of 20 `char`s, and you're trying to assign a pointer (`"McLove"`, a compile time string, e.g., a `const char*`) to an array (a `char[]`), which won't work.

To *copy* the data `"McLove"` into the array, you need to use `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(pt->lastname, "McLove", 20); // 20 is the size of the array, change it when your array size changes, or better yet, use a constant for both
```

Or better yet, use `std::string`:

```
struct testing {
    string lastname;
};

testing* pt = new testing;

pt->lastname = "McLove";
```

And now that will work, because `std::string` has an `operator=` that works with `const char*`.

As a side note, don't needlessly allocate objects on the free store (using `new`); allocate them on the stack:

```
testing pt; // not: testing* pt = new testing;

testing.lastname = "McLove"; // with std::string
```

Comment: No, don't use `strncpy`; it's *not* just a bounds-checked version of `strcpy`.  If you give it a target size that's bigger than the length of the source string, it will (needlessly) pad the target with null bytes; if the target size is smaller, the target won't be null-terminated at all (i.e., it won't be a valid string).  If you want the equivalent of what `strncpy` probably *should* have been, you can assign a `'\0'` to the first byte of the target and then use `strncat`.  (Yes, for C++ you probably just want to use `std::string`.)

Comment: Forgive my possible ignorance but, unless speed is terribly important, what's wrong with `strncpy` padding the target string with `'\0'`s?  Sure, that's a little more functionality than one might expect but what does it hurt in non-kludged code?

Comment: @chaos I personally wouldn't care, but the non-null-terminating behaviour if the buffer is too small is worth the switch to me.

Answer (score 2):

The type of a string literal is `pointer to const char`. You can use that to *initialize* an array of char, but you can't assign to an array of char (from that or anything else).

Since you're apparently doing C++, you probably want:

```
struct testing { 
     std::string lastname;
};

testing pt;
pt.lastname = "McLove";
```

Allocating an object like `testing` dynamically is fairly unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign one array to another. You're going to need to use `strcpy` (or better, `strncpy`).

Comment: No, not `strncpy`; see my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

Because string literals in C++ have the type `const char[N]` where `N` is the length of the literal, including the NULL character. So you're trying to assign a `const char[7]` to a array of type `char[20]`, exactly what the compiler told you. Since arrays are not assignable this is invalid.

Use `strcpy` instead

```
strcpy( p-lastname, "McLove" );
```

Of course, you should also check if the destination is large enough to hold the source, or use some variant of `strcpy` that does this.